# Avoid calculating null values into nested SQL query

Tags: postgresql, nested, case

I have a PostgreSQL calculation calculating `roi` where several values of `select 100 * ((SUM(time_product)/SUM(rt_id_count))*SUM(rental_cost))/SUM(sale_count)` are defined and calculated with case statements as nested queries. However, if any of the values is empty, (like if `rental_cost` is missing for an item), it calculates the `roi` as `zero`, and that zero value is getting rolled into the average getting calculated, skewing the average downwards. How can I treat these zeros as null in the total calculation?

(I've taken out some of the nested queries and replaced them with `[calculation]` in the question; it's mainly because it's a very long query, and I want to filter out the noise and make the full structure more visible)

```
  (select 100 * ((SUM(time_product)/SUM(rt_id_count))*SUM(rental_cost))/SUM(sale_count)  FROM

  (select p2.id, p2.inventory_type, p2.working_value, COUNT(distinct p2.id),

  ----nested values calculated here
   (case p2.inventory_type 
      when 'set' then 
      [calculation A]
    else [calculation B] end) rental_cost,
    (case p2.inventory_type 
      when 'set' then 
      [caluculation A]
    else [calculation B]  end)   sale_count,
    (case p2.inventory_type 
      when 'set' then count(distinct rt.id)
      else 1 end 
      ) rt_id_count,
    (case p2.inventory_type 
      when 'set' then 
      [calculation ]  end)   time_total,
 [calculation]  time_product

  FROM warehouses w
    LEFT JOIN rfid_tags rt ON w.id = rt.location_id AND rt.location_type = 'Warehouse'
    LEFT JOIN products p2 ON rt.ancestor_product_id = p2.id 
    LEFT JOIN category_assignments ca  ON ca.product_id = p2.id
    LEFT JOIN categories c ON ca.category_id = c.id
    LEFT JOIN product_selections ps ON ps.rfid_tag_id = rt.id 

    WHERE 
      c.id=categories.id AND ca.primary = true  AND w.id=warehouses.id
      AND (select count(ps.id) from product_selections ps where ps.rfid_tag_id=rt.id)>0
      and p2.working_value>0 
    AND rt.location_id=w.id
    group by p2.id, p2.inventory_type, p2.working_value, c.sale_price_percentage, c.rental_price_percentage) Z) roi
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`NULLIF`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-NULLIF) to return `NULL` if both parameters are equal:

```
SELECT NULLIF(?, 0);
```

where `?` is your computation.

This would mean for your case:

```
select nullif(100 * ((SUM(time_product)/SUM(rt_id_count))*SUM(rental_cost))/SUM(sale_count), 0)
from ...
```